# need sample web service for testing

Tags: json, web-services, wsdl, ionic-framework

Just I need sample json web service in this format can provide url for this.

```
[
{num:"1",descript:"consumer",status:"closed",casedet:"completed"},
{num:"2",descript:"literal",status:"open",casedet:"initiated"},
{num:"3",descript:"literal",status:"closed",casedet:"completed"},
{num:"4",descript:"consumer",status:"open",casedet:"process"}
];
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You may find a lot resources if you search the internet.

Try [this](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums), [this](http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo), [this](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)